# Form submission does not save input value in 1 click but after 2

Tags: php, html, mysql

Something very strange is happening here.
This code below (automatic input values after dropdown selection) does not get saved in the database with 1 click on submit but after 2 clicks. Is there a simple fix for this or do I need an different approach here?

```
<?php $id = (ISSET($_GET['client'])) ? intval($_GET['client']):0; ?>

<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>

<form class="edit" action="" method="post"> 

<?php
$a = $row['costs'];
$b = $row['deposit'];
$c = $a-$b;

$auto6 = $a*1.06;
$auto21 = $a*1.21;

?>  

        <select id="btw" name="btw" class="input-xlarge">
            <option value="Verlegd"<?=$row['btw'] == 'Verlegd' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Verlegd</option>
            <option value="6%"<?=$row['btw'] == '6%' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>6%</option>
            <option value="21%"<?=$row['btw'] == '21%' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>21%</option>
        </select>       

        <strong>Total excl BTW:</strong><input id="btw0" class="special <?=$row['btw'] != 'Verlegd' ? 'disabled' : 'enabled';?>" type="text" name="exclbtw" value="<?=$row['btw'] == 'Verlegd' ? $a : '';?>">
        <strong>Total incl BTW 21%:</strong><input id="btw21" class="special <?=$row['btw'] != '21%' ? 'disabled' : 'enabled';?>" type="text" name="btw21" value="<?=$row['btw'] == '21%' ? $auto21 : '';?>">
        <strong>Total incl BTW 6%:</strong><input id="btw6" class="special <?=$row['btw'] != '6%' ? 'disabled' : 'enabled';?>" type="text" name="btw6" value="<?=$row['btw'] == '6%' ? $auto6 : '';?>">

    <INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Save" NAME="Submit">
</form>
<?php } ?>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

$btw = $_POST['btw'];
$exclbtw = $_POST['exclbtw'];
$btw21 = $_POST['btw21'];
$btw6 = $_POST['btw6'];

$update = "UPDATE 
           invoice
           SET

            btw = '$btw',
            exclbtw = '$exclbtw',
            btw21 = '$btw21',
            btw6 = '$btw6'

           WHERE 
           id = $id";

           $conn->query($update) or die("Cannot update");
}
?>

<?php
if($update){//if the update worked
echo("<script>window.location = 'http://example.com/invoice/edit.php?client=$id';</script>");
} else {
    "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: A) Do you see any errors client-side (JavaScript console) or server-side (error log)? B) What does "work" mean? What is supposed to happen? C) Where is the `<form>` tag and action defined?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Do you have error logging turned on? Do you know where it is? There could be any number of things going wrong and you must be aware of them, especially the dreaded "blank page" type issues.

Comment: @tadman. I don't know how I can turn that on. I have a shared hosting. Im new to php.

Comment: First stop might be a guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) but don't forget that the [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/) can be a great source of information. That and queries like "enable error logging {my hosting provider name}". A lot of programming skill boils down to knowing where to look and how to understand what you find.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the information. I will use the guide. But how about the issue that I have right now. Where can I start find a fix? I think that something is going wrong with the calculation. So in the dropdown the option is selected but the value does not get the calculation after the option is selected. So there is no error but there is missing something for the value to get the calculation immediately after dropdown option is selected. So the calculation starts after 1 click on submit and the second click saves the calculated value

Comment: is the client variable passed on the URL string at page load to complete the where clause?  If not it would be trying to update where ID = 0.  I see it's passed after the $update is true. Perhaps that is why it takes two submit clicks?

Comment: @user1628449 No that works fine. Thank you.

Comment: as tadman said you need to debug it at this point. If nothing else, echo everything out so that you can view all variables. Also, do read up on prepared statements. The learning curve can be steep at first but once you grasp the concepts, they're not bad.

Comment: @user1628449 Okay I turned errors on and it says "Notice: Undefined variable: update"

Comment: One clue from the code to aid in debugging. It appears that you may be creating multiple forms with the same ID attribute. Is that the case (view source in the browser to see the generated code)?

Comment: @SloanThrasher No there is only 1 form.

Comment: Based on your previous comment, it appears that if the previous if statement (```if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){```) is false, then the $update variable isn't created.

Comment: @SloanThrasher How can this be false as 2 clicks on submit does work?

Comment: The error message should also give you a line number that caused the error. Add a line before the if statement like ```$update = '';```. You have to eliminate errors in the order they're reported. Once that's done, you'll probably find the problem causing the click twice behavior.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have put the if($update) inside the isset submit and now the errors are gone. But still need to press twice on submit to save the values :((

Comment: Your browser should have some debug features, in particular a console. It can tell you if the page is being submitted with the first click. If so, that would be a useful clue to the problem. Also, is there any Javascript used in the page?

Comment: That's an important clue. It means that the if statement is false. Use the browser's console to see what is being sent to the server.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Yes there are some Javascripts but it's from bootstrap for the modal popup stuff. In the first click on submit, other data on the same page like firstname and so on does get saved. But the calculated data needs 2 clicks?

Comment: @SloanThrasher what do you mean by "what is being sent to the server"?

Comment: The data sent to the server by the browser when you click the submit button. You do use the browser's debugger, right?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I think you mean the files inside the network tab. The file that is the page is the same name with the correct client id. So nothing wrong with that I guess

Comment: Nope, not there. In the console it should show anything sent or received, including things like header, data sent and received. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193069/discussion-between-sloan-thrasher-and-chocoprins18).

Comment: @SloanThrasher no, seeing the data sent and received is the job of the Network section of the browser's developer tools. Console is for JavaScript related stuff. If you're teaching someone to use this stuff it really helps to get the terminology correct. Also, in Chrome, since OP is not using AJAX, then to see the previous request before a postback, it's necessary to click the "Preserve log" box in the Network tab, otherwise the data will be wiped after each postback